# Semver: Is it acceptable for "latest pre-release" package to be older than "latest stable?"

Tags: semantic-versioning, npm-publish

According to semver.org, there are conventions for pre-release and stable version numbers, but I haven't found conventions for NPM distribution tags. Since we can only apply a single NPM distribution tag with `npm publish` or with `package.json`'s `publishConfig.tag` field, I am currently publishing distribution tags such that `latest` will be newer than `alpha` when we graduate our alpha packages.

Eg.

```
latest: 1.0.1
alpha: 1.0.1-alpha.0
```

Comment: NPM tags have nothing to do with SemVer.  The [SemVer spec](https://semver.org/) covers version string syntax, semantics and precedence ordering, nothing else. Take up tooling issues with the makers of your tools.

Comment: https://npm.community/

Comment: Fair, that's why I also tagged this q with `npm`.